# Troubleshooting a method challenge with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Simple question here. I never programmed in ruby... so I thought I asked here to confirm if I'm even close to the solution.

Challenge:

Problem Definition: This Ruby method should ensure that the word "Twitter" is spelt correctly.

```
def fix_spelling(name)
  if name = "twittr"
    name = "twitter"
  else
    fix_spelling(name)
  end
  return "name"
end
```

I checked how to build methods in ruby and I came out with the following solution:

The problems I identified:

1. the method is being called inside the function so it will never print anything.
2. the return is actually returning a string "name" rather that the variable.

```
def fix_spelling(name)
  if name = "twittr"
    name = "twitter"
  end
  return name
end

puts fix_spelling("twittr")
```

Would this be correct?

Priting:

```
def fix_spelling(name)
  if name == "twittr"
    name  = "twitter"
  end
  return name
end


puts fix_spelling(name = "twittr");
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. In your first code you actually have infinite recursion if the string is anything other than "twittr", because `fix_spelling` will call `fix_spelling`, and this would continue infinitely, never finishing

Comment: I thought so... I did think this will be connected to recursion. However, I test it in Repl.it and when I call the method it yields the twittr. any ideas? I just edited the main question and added how I had to call it and it worked! How else can you call this? out of curiosity! cheer man!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. The last version in your question works correctly and you can easily prove it by copy'n'pasting the code into the IRB console. The other two version do not work as you already noticed. What is actually your question?

Comment: Your code contains 115 characters, which is well below 280, so I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing and Shortening the Original Code

A much shorter and more idiomatic version of your current solution looks like this:

```rb
def fix_spelling name
  name == 'twittr' ? 'twitter' : name
end
```

```rb
# validate inputs
p %w[twitter twittr twit].map { |word| fix_spelling word }
#=> ["twitter", "twitter", "twit"]
```

However, this essentially just returns *name* for any other value than `twittr`, whether it's spelled correctly or not. If that's what you expect, fine. Otherwise, you'll need to develop a set of case statements or return values that can "correct" all sorts of other misspellings. You might also consider using the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or other heuristic for fuzzy matching rather than using fixed strings or regular expressions to map your inputs to outputs.

### Fuzzy Matching

Consider this alternative approach, which uses a gem to determine if the [Damerau-Levenshtein](https://github.com/GlobalNamesArchitecture/damerau-levenshtein) edit distance is ~50% of the length of your correctly-spelled word, allows for additional words, and returns the original word bracketed by question marks when it can't be corrected:

```rb
require 'damerau-levenshtein'

WORD_LIST = %w[Facebook Twitter]

def autocorrect word
  WORD_LIST.map do |w| 
    max_dist = (w.length / 2).round
    return w if DamerauLevenshtein.distance(w, word) <= max_dist 
  end 
  '?%s?' % word
end

# validate inputs
p %w[twitter twittr twit facebk].map { |word| autocorrect word }
#=> ["Twitter", "Twitter", "?twit?", "Facebook"]
```

This isn't really a "spellchecker in a box," but provides a foundation for a more flexible framework if that's where you're going with this. There are a lot of edge cases such as correct-word mapping, capitalization, word stemming, and abbreviations (think "fb" for Facebook) that I'm excluding from the scope of this answer, but edit distance will certainly get you further along towards a comprehensive auto-correct solution than the original example would. Your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that in Ruby you also have ternary expressions :)